# Populate html dropdownlist with fetched mysql data using Node.js/Express.js

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, node.js, express

Attempting to populate a select dropdownlist with data using Express.js.

**Project Structure**

[image]

**users table**

[image]

MySQL config file

**dbConnection.js**

```
const mysql = require('mysql');

var dbConnection = mysql.createConnection({
    host:      'localhost',         // database host
    user:       'horation',         // your database username
    password: 'hmsvictory',         // your database password
    port:       3306,               // default MySQL port
    db:       'display_images'         // your database name
});
dbConnection.connect((err) => {
if (err) throw err;
console.log('Connected to MySQL Server!');
});

module.exports = dbConnection;
```

**index.js**

```
'use strict';
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var _sql = require("mysql");

var myConnection  = require('express-myconnection');

var _config = require('../DataStore/dbConnection');
 var dbOptions = {
    host:      _config.host,
    user:       _config.user,
    password: _config.password,
    database: _config.db
                }

app.use(myConnection(_sql, dbOptions, 'pool'));

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function (req, res) {
_sql.connect(_config.dbConnection()).then(() => {
    return _sql.query`SELECT name FROM studentinfo`
}).then(result => {
    console.log(result); 
    // Pass the DB result to the template
    res.render('/index', {dropdownVals: result.recordset});
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err)
})
});
module.exports = router;
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
 </head>
<body>
    <h1>Binding MySQL data to a DropDownList</h1>
    <label>Name: </label>
   <select>
      <% for (const i in dropdownVals) { %>
        <option value="<%= dropdownVals[i].id %>"> <%= dropdownVals[i].name %> </option>
    <% } %>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```
const express = require('express'),
path = require('path') // add path module,
  app = express(),
  cors = require('cors'),
  bodyParser = require('body-parser');

// make server object that contain port property and the value for our server.
var server = {
  port: 4040
};

// routers
const router = require('./routes/index');

// use the modules
app.use(cors())
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true})) // parsing incoming requests with urlencoded based body-parser


// use router
app.use('/index', router);
// router user input
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname,'views') + '/index.html');
 });

// starting the server
app.listen( server.port, () => console.log(`Server started, listening port: ${server.port}`));
```

Running the above code, I'm getting this:

[image]

However, I was expecting to get this dropdownlist:

[image]

**Required**:

How can I fetch MySQL data from users table and display in index.html dropownlist?

Answer (score 0):

I was expecting help from here, however, in the meantime, I managed to change app.js file to this and it worked!

```
'use strict';
const express = require('express'); 
const path = require('path');// add path module,
const cors = require('cors');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const engine = require('consolidate');

const app = express();


// view engine setup
 app.set('views', __dirname+ '/views');
 // make server object that contain port property and the value for our server.
 //app.engine('html', engine.mustache);
 app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
 app.set('view engine', 'html');

 // routers
 const apiRouter = require('./routes/index');

 // use the modules
 app.use(cors());
 app.use(bodyParser.json());
 app.use(express.json())
 app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true})) // parsing incoming requests with urlencoded based body-parser


 // use router
 app.use('/', apiRouter);
 // router user input
 app.get('*', function(req, res){
   res.render('index.html');
 });

  const server = {
  port: 4040
};

// starting the server
 app.listen(server.port, () => console.log(`Server started, listening port: ${server.port}`));
```

Happy coding